# Replace pattern and add square brackets around digit

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to replace `llr0` with `tmpLLR[0]` for all digits [0-9]. So `llr7` would go to `tmpLLR[7]`.

I've tried `:%s/llr[0-9]/tmpLLR\[&\]/gc` but this produces `tmpLLR[llr7]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to put the captured groups within escaped parentheses and access the captured values from `\1`, `\2` onwards,

```
:%s/llr\([0-9]\)/tmpLLR\[\1\]/gc
```

As noted int the comments section of the answer, using `\v` seems to enable a magic mode in its [pattern matching](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cv) on which you could just do

```
:%s/\vllr(\d)/tmpLLR\[\1\]/gc
```

Comment: Also, `[0-9]` could just be `\d`, and `\v` could make it more readable: `:%s/\vllr(\d)/tmpLLR\[\1\]/gc`